# Tracker: why remove computation when invalidated?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-tracker

I am reading the [tracker manual](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual#the-trackercomputation-object) and having a hard time understanding something.

I understand that `dependency.changed()` will invalidate all computations in the dependency, causing the tracker to rerun.

But why does Meteor delete the computation from the dependency when invalidated?

For instance, here is a Tracker example from the manual:

```
Dependency.prototype.depend = function () {
  var self = this;
  if (Tracker.currentComputation) {
    var id = self._nextId++;
    self._dependents[id] = Tracker.currentComputation;
    Tracker.currentComputation.onInvalidate(function () { # Here
      delete self._dependents[id];                        # Here
    });                                                   # Here
  }
};

Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  for (var id in this._dependents) {
    this._dependents[id].invalidate();
  }
};
```

Why do we care to add `Tracker.currentComputation.onInvalidate()` callback to delete computation from the dependency? It seems unnecessary to me.

I would like to understand this fully. Any ideas?

Comment: I think invalidating the computation will cause it to re-run, so it will most likely register the dependency again anyway. In some cases it might not and in that case we want the dependency to be cleared for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider this Tracker.autorun function:

```
Tracker.autorun(()=>{
    if(dependency1.get()>10){
        console.log(dependency2.get());
    }
});
```

It is pretty simple, it will log every `dependency2` changes as long as `dependency1` is higher than 10. Now, if on a computation the `dependency1` is lower than 11, it will only depend on it. While if the computation runs when `dependency1` is higher than 10, it will depend on both dependencies.

If you do not remove dependencies and `dependency1` gets equal or lower to 10, the tracker will still run every time `dependency2` changes, although nothing much will happen. This could become a real performance issue on big autoruns.